# Angular factory with parameters

Tags: angularjs

I have a small factory which requests data from a database (through php pages which return json objects).  However to do this I need to set certain parameters in the get request. I have created a factory object to make the request.

```
app.factory('getplayerfactory', function($http){
return{
        getPlayer: function(callback, name, currentinnings) {
            var file = "/ajax.php?file=getplayer&displayname="+name+"&currentinnings="+currentinnings
            $http.get(file).success(callback)
        }
    }
})// end of getplayersfactory
```

(I am using npm coding standard so no semi colons at the end of lines)

In my controller I want to call this factory and then use the results to fill data.  I have tried to use the following to call this

```
getplayerfactory.getPlayer(function(results, "M. Millent", 1){
    $scope.players[0].setHowout(results.howout)
})
```

However this creates an error when I introduce more parameters than results.  I have used this factory pattern with other $http data request where the get request does not need parameters which works fine.

How do I make a get request which sets parameters? or do I need to create  a separate factory for each set of parameters?

Comment: Heads up npm is for nodejs not client side scripting.  You may have troubles minifying code (semi colons and array syntax for di).

Comment: Semicolon guys Again -http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

Answer (score 1):

`function(results, "M. Millent", 1) {` is not a valid function signature

I think this is what you meant:

```
getplayerfactory.getPlayer(function(results){
    $scope.players[0].setHowout(results.howout)
}, "M. Millent", 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I am new to Javascript and it sometimes takes me a while to understand how it actually works.  I see my error now.